# Can I use the outer() or apply() function with 2-dimensional vectors?

Tags: r, for-loop, performance, outer-join

I'm working with intervals, and I would like to have an efficient way to find the distance between each interval. The distance functions all take two 2-dimensional vectors. I need to put every row against every other row in the nx2 data frame.

Here's the code I have now (inside distance is just an example function, but all the functions take the same input):

```
# Inside takes vectors I1 and I2
inside <- function(I1, I2) min(I1[1]-I2[2], I2[1]-I1[2])
# the example intervals are (0,1), (1,2), and (4,5).
I <- data.frame(l=c(0,1,4), u=c(1,2,5))
n <- nrow(I)

d <- matrix(rep(NA, n^2), nrow=n)
# I'm ashamed that I wrote nested for loops (I have no programming training)
for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        d[i,j] <- inside(I[i,],I[j,])
    }
}
```

This is part of a simulation study, so this code must be run thousands of times. Since it uses a nested for loop, it's appallingly inefficient. Here's the code I would like to use:

```
index <- 1:nrow(I)
d <- outer(index, index, function(x, y) inside(I[x,], I[y,]))
```

If that code worked, I wouldn't be here asking for your help.

I would also be fine if I could somehow get apply() to work. Anything to speed up my shameful for loops!

Comment: You should know that `apply` will in general not really be significantly faster than (well written) for loops.

Comment: and `Vectorize` only hides `mapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a vectorized version of `inside`:

```
vecInside <- Vectorize(function(x, y) inside(I[x, ], I[y, ]))
```

Second, use this function in outer:

```
outer(index, index, vecInside)
```

The result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1   -2   -5
[2,]   -2   -1   -4
[3,]   -5   -4   -1
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured this out. I assumed outer() worked like apply() and accepted custom scalar functions. It still isn't very fast, but it's much faster!

Answer (score 3):

The `v_outer` function (vectorized `outer`) in `qdaTools` works for this sort of task:

```
library(qdapTools)
v_outer(t(I), inside)

##    V1 V2 V3
## V1 -1 -2 -5
## V2 -2 -1 -4
## V3 -5 -4 -1
```